# How to handle exceptions from promises in TypeScript with async await?

Tags: typescript, error-handling, promise, async-await

I am trying to find a nice way of handling exceptions in TypeScript with promises with async/await

Here's what I have so far

```
    private async initDirectoryEntry(cacheDirectoryName: string): Promise<DirectoryEntry> {
        const cacheDirectoryEntry = await this.resolveLocalFileSystemDirectory(this.file.cacheDirectory);
        return this.file.getDirectory(cacheDirectoryEntry as DirectoryEntry, cacheDirectoryName, { create: true })
    }

    private async resolveLocalFileSystemDirectory(path: string): Promise<DirectoryEntry|Error> {
        return new Promise<DirectoryEntry>((resolve, reject) =>
            this.localFileSystem.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
                path,
                (entry) => {
                    if (!entry.isDirectory) {
                        reject(new Error(`${path} is not a directory`))
                    } else {
                        resolve(entry as DirectoryEntry);
                    }
                },
                (error) => reject(error))
        )

    }
```

The code itself compiles, but I found it annoying that I had to specify `|Error` in the Promise return type and do the explicit cast in the initDirectoryEntry.

Not sure if I am doing something improper here.  I am thinking I should be able to say something like `throws Exception` or something like that and catch it accordingly.

Comment: `|Error` here is wrong because `T` in `Promise<T>` is type of resolved value. `reject` always gets `any` value. So in your case `Promise<DirectoryEntry>` is enough. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts#L33

Comment: Error handling on `await`ed promises is done with `try`/`catch`, but that doesn't appear to be your actual question nor relevant in the code example. Can you please update the title of your question?